# How to reshape scanned input of pairs of data from data set with unequal numbers of columns

Tags: r

I have pairs of data scanned where the number of pairs on a line is variable in number.

R code:

```
x <- scan(paste0(dirdata,"df.txt"), what = "", sep = " ")

Lines in data set look like
 v1  v2  v3   v4   v5  v6   V7  V8
"A" "35" "B" "32" "Z" "67"  "F" 17
"F" "17"  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA
```

I want to reshape it to look like

```
 v1  v2
"A" "35" 
"B" "32"
"Z" "67"
"F" "17"
```

Can this be done in base R? How? in reshape package? How?
I am doing things two ways (1) using base R code and (2) using a package such as reshape.

Output from an unlist function is given below.

```
d1 <- data.frame(v1 = unlist(df1[,c(TRUE, FALSE)]), 
                 v2 = unlist(df1[,c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
data.frame(lapply(d1, na.omit))

   head(d1)
      v1 v2
V21    A  1
V22    B 50
V23    Z 74
V24    F  3
```

Can someone explain what the unlist function is doing and is column one of the output line numbers?

Can you help, please? Thanks.
MM

Comment: I can't replicate your output with the data I showed.  May be you have factor columns.  Your examples are not reproducible as I mentioned in the earlier post.  `Lines in data set look like`. What are these Lines.  Is it a `data.frame` or a single string.  It is better to use `dput` for sharing data

Answer (score 0):

If it is data.frame

```
d1 <- data.frame(v1 = unlist(df1[,c(TRUE, FALSE)]), 
                v2 = unlist(df1[,c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
data.frame(lapply(d1, na.omit))
#  v1 v2
#1  A 35
#2  F 17
#3  B 32
#4  Z 67
#5  F 17
```

---

or using `reshape` from `base R`

```
na.omit(reshape(transform(df1, rn = seq_len(nrow(df1))),
   direction = 'long', idvar = 'rn', 
  varying = list(seq(1, ncol(df1),  by = 2), seq(2, ncol(df1), by = 2)))[3:4])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("A", "F"), v2 = c(35L, 17L), v3 = c("B", 
NA), v4 = c(32L, NA), v5 = c("Z", NA), v6 = c(67L, NA), V7 = c("F", 
NA), V8 = c(17L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You are challenging me again. Please see the edited post. Thanks. MM

Comment: @MaryA.Marion What is the issue with this soluiton?